# callback is not a function node js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am new to javascript and i am having trouble solving this error. I get the message: "callback is not a function" at:"return callback(rolesArray)".

```js
Rol.getAllRoles = function(callback){
    sql = "select role from Role;";
    var rolesArray = [];
    var role;
    mysql.connection(function(err,conn){
        if (err){
            return callback(err);
        }
        conn.query(sql,function(err,rows){
            if (err){
                return callback(err);
            }
            for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
                role = rows[i].role;
                rolesArray.push(rol);
            }
            console.log("roles: " + rolesArray);
            return callback(rolesArray);
        });
    });   
}
```

The console.log outputs:"roles: admin,customer" so the connection with the database works.

Comment: how do you call `Rol.getAllRoles`, aparently is that you are not passing a callback

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  One thing you should know about stack overflow is that when you post a question, your best chance for an answer is in the first 30 minutes or so after posting (that's when the most people see it, particularly if your question is on a busy tag).  As such, when someone engages with your question to ask you something about it, you should be around to answer that comment.  This is not like other online forums where you post a question and come back the next day. Your question may be closed within a short time if it's not entirely clear and you are not around to clarify.

Comment: So, it's now been over an hour since you posted and you were asked for some clarification on your question and you have not responded.  You should check back at least a couple times in the first 15-30 minutes after asking to make sure your question was understood and to interact with anyone who is asking questions or posting answers.  That's how you make sure we properly understand your question and that the answers are going in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

That error means that you are not passing a function to `Rol.getAllRoles(fn)` when you call it.

In addition, so that you can have proper error handling in your callback and so you can more easily distinguish between an error and the actual data, you should always pass a first argument to the callback that indicates whether there was an error or not and then the second argument (if not an error) can be your results array like this:

```
Rol.getAllRoles = function(callback){
    sql = "select role from Role;";
    var rolesArray = [];
    var role;
    mysql.connection(function(err,conn){
        if (err){
            return callback(err);
        }
        conn.query(sql,function(err,rows){
            if (err){
                return callback(err);
            }
            for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
                role = rows[i].role;
                rolesArray.push(rol);
            }
            console.log("roles: " + rolesArray);
            // make sure the first argument to the callback
            // is an error value, null if no error
            return callback(null, rolesArray);
        });
    });   
}
```

And, then you should be calling it like this:

```
Rol.getAllRoles(function(err, rolesArray) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error here
    } else {
        // process rolesArray here
    }
});
```

This style of calling an async callback as in `callback(err, data)` is a very common async callback design pattern.  It allows all callers to see if there was an error or not and if there was no error to get access to the final result.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```js
Rol.getAllRoles = function(callback){
    var sql = "select role from Role;";
    var rolesArray = [];
    var role;
    callback = callback || function(){};
    mysql.connection(function(err,conn){
        if (err){
            return callback(err);
        }
        conn.query(sql,function(err,rows){
            if (err){
                return callback(err);
            }
            for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++){
                role = rows[i].role;
                rolesArray.push(rol);
            }
            console.log("roles: " + rolesArray);
            return callback(rolesArray);
        });
    });   
}
```

This way you enforce that callback is always a function. If you run it like Rol.getAllRoles() then you would get an error previously. Now you wont. You wont get any data back though.

Make sure you are calling Rol.getAllRoles with the proper parameter (ie: a function).

Comment: This might eliminate the error, but if the OP isn't passing a proper callback, then they can't get the results of the database query so it seems hard to see how this could possibly be a useful change or a solution to the OP's problem.  The goal is both BOTH fix the error AND get the result back from the operation.  This does not accomplish both.

Comment: You didn't read my whole answer did you? Specifically the last two paragraphs.

Comment: I read that - is that what you're saying is the operative part of the answer?  It's' just that you aren't really answering the question.  And, even if they do pass a proper function, the calling convention makes it difficult to distinguish between success and error.  There's more to it than this - it's not a complete answer.  You don't suggest a way to hide an error that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: So post your own answer and leave my answer alone. No need to be a dick about it, or him not responding yet.

Comment: I did post my own answer.  And, comments are for us to tell you what we think of your answer.  That's what they are for.  Some authors choose to read the feedback they get and improve their answer rather than complaining about getting feedback.

Comment: My note to the OP about not responding yet is to educate the OP about how best to use stack overflow.  Those of us who spend a lot of time in this community help others learn how to be good stack overflow citizens while getting the most benefit out of the community themselves.

Comment: Your idea of constructive feedback is rather harsh. You know it takes very little time to try to be nice to people. You'll find it helps make interactions go very smoothly.

Yes I can improve my answer, but why should I. You've already posted what I could improve mine to.